# TextField format: .number fit settings number format

Tags: swift, swiftui, formatting

I have the following code for formatting a string in a TextField. However, it doesn't adhere to the rules set in the settings, meaning for a string like 123456.00, I get 123,456.00 instead of 123456,00.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State var value: Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value ?? 0, format: .number)")
                .font(.title)
            TextField("0.0",
                      value: $value,
                      format: .number.locale(.current))
            .onSubmit {
                print("asdas")
            }
            .focused($isFocused)
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if isFocused {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            isFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Is there a different way to achieve this, or am I missing something?

Comment: TextFIeld format: .number shouldn't react on change format in settings?

Comment: Not really but it's not clear what "settings" are in this case.

Comment: Interesting. Using the old `NumberFormatter` works, but not `FloatingPointFormatStyle`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think "settings" refers to the built-in "Settings" app. The specific settings can be found at "General" -> "Language and Region".

Comment: Sweeper your right and also don't don't why FloatingPointFormatStyle is not fit to this purpose. For now I decide to use NumberFormatter with ```formatter.zeroSymbol = ""``` instead optional Double.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct HomeView: View {
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
@State var value: Double?

private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
    formatter.groupingSeparator = ""
    return formatter
}()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(value.map { numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) } ?? "0,00")
            .font(.title)
        TextField("0.0", value: $value, formatter: numberFormatter)
            .onSubmit {
                print("asdas")
            }
            .focused($isFocused)
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if isFocused {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            isFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer clearly explains what was wrong in the question and it clearly explains how the answer resolves the issue. Please update your answer with more details explaining your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).